# Plotting piecewise functions in maple

Tags: maple

How would I plot this function in maple?

f(x)= 1 if x is rational, 0 otherwise.

Also I want this to be within the interval 0<=x<=1

Answer (score 2):

That function is not piecewise, and it cannot be plotted by any software. It's theoretically impossible. The best that you could do is plot a line segment from (0,1) to (1,1) to represent the rationals and another from (0,0) to (0,1) to represent the irrationals.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question now but is a good place to clarify just what a computer program could mean by "rational" and "irrational".

As a first attempt you could try to define your desired function this way:

```
f1 := x -> `if`(x::rational, 1, 0):
```

A few test cases seem to be giving us what we want:

```
> f1(3), f1(3/2), f1(Pi), f1(sqrt(2));
               1, 1, 0, 0
```

However we then run into this:

```
> f1(1.5);
                   0
```

What gives? Since f(3/2)=1, we might expect f(1.5) to be the same. The explanation is that the check x::rational is checking that the input x is of the Maple type rational, which is an integer or a fraction. A Maple fraction is an ordered pair of integers (numerator and denominator) which is structurally different from a floating-point number.

A broader interpretation of the mathematical meaning of 'rational' would  include the floating-point numbers. So we can broaden that definition and write:

```
 f2 := x -> `if`(x::{rational,float}, 1, 0}:
```

and then we have the desired f2(1.5)=1.

But both of these are useless for plotting.  When Maple plots something, it generates a set of sample points from the specified interval, all of which will be floating-point numbers. Of our previously-defined functions, f1 will then return zero for all these points, while f2 will return 1.

You won't do any better with other software. If you were to take a truly uniform sample of *n* points from some real interval, your resulting points would be irrational (in fact, transcendental).  Almost all such numbers cannot be represented on a computer because they cannot be represented in any compact form, so any software that attempts such sampling will simply return a collection of *n* results with terminating decimal expansions.

As Carl suggested you can generate something resembling the plot you want with

```
> plot([0,1]);
```